# User Defined Base URL With Retrofit

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

The application I work on must use a different Base URL for every user. Basically the user has his own server, and in the application he must specify the IP Address for his server in a Text Field so the application can start doing HTTP Requests to that server.

When I create the Retrofit instance it requires a Base URL, but there is now way I can access it from the UI, since the user has to enter the base URL manually from a Text Field.

As a workaround I just pass Google as the Base URL when I create the Retrofit instance and then use the @URL Annotation to pass the whole URL, but from what I know the @URL Annotation is limited to GET and POST Requests.

```
return new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://google.com")
    .build();
```

Is There any better way to achieve this or should I stick to the @URL Annotation?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

you can add a parameters when calling that

```
getApiService(userBaseUrl : string){
....
....
return new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(userBaseUrl)
    .build();
}
```